# Why is the superlative of "nah" not "am nähsten" but "am nächsten"?

Tags: adjective

I'm wondering why the adjective "nah" (near / close) has the superlative "am nächsten" and not "am nähsten", esp. as "(der / die) nächste" means "(the) next" and not "the nearest / closest".

Comment: You could make the argument that the "closest" will be the next one.

Comment: At first I was thinking so, too, but the next (e.g. item to work on) is not necessarily the closest one.

Comment: Technically in English "next" *does* mean the *nearest*, and so does in German.

Comment: That would be new to me, as "next" usually is [translated](https://www.dict.cc/?s=next) as "danach", "folgende", "kommende", all of which have a differnt meaning than (geographically) closest.

Comment: @sschuberth In your examples you're using "next" as temporal next in time (where you should really use "after" instead), therefore *danach* and so forth. If I say _"you're sitting next to me"_ this *does* mean that you are sitting the nearest geographically possible to me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*(Ich antworte der Einfachheit halber auf Deutsch und nehme aufgrund des Namens und der Herkunftsangabe des Fragestellers an, dass er den Beitrag verstehen wird.)*

Ich denke die Antwort ist im Grunde recht naheliegend, wenn man die Etymologie von *nah* kennt: Im Mittelhochdeutschen gab es zwei Parallelformen für "nah", nämlich *nāch* (mit seltenerer verkürzter Form *nā*) und daneben *nāhe*. Erstere war die mit Abstand dominante Variante:

[image]
(aus [KSW II.1](http://d-nb.info/1127762753): 331; die tiefgestellten Zahlen geben die absolute Zahl von Korpusbelegen an)

Der Gebrauch änderte sich im Frühneuhochdeutschen. Im Positiv wird grundsätzlich *nah(e)* verwendet, im Komparativ *näher*, der Superlativ ist aber schon dort *nächst* und folgt somit schlicht der vorherrschenden mittelhochdeutschen Form. In der *Frühneuhochdeutschen Grammatik* (1993: § M 55) bezeichnen Solms/Wegera diesen abweichenden Superlativ-Stamm als Ergebnis eines "historische[n] Lautprozesse[s]", darauf hinweisend, dass auch die "Ausgleichsform" *nahest* "gelegentlich" belegt sei. Umgekehrt war tatsächlich auch noch die alte *-ch*-Form im Frühneuhochdeutschen vereinzelt im Positiv und Komparativ anzutreffen, war also dort auch noch nicht zur Gänze abgebaut (Frühneuhochdeutsches Wörterbuch, Bd.9.2 [2019], Eintrag "nahe").

Comment: Das war aber mal eine fundierte Antwort! Und noch dazu eine, die auf eine "warum"-Frage antwortet, was ja meistens fast unmöglich ist. Hut ab.

Comment: Interessant. Selbst als Deutsch-Muttersprachler war ich lange Zeit der Meinung, dass es auch "am nähsten" gibt und es streng genommen der richtigere Superlativ wäre, schlicht und einfach weil "nah" und "nächste" genau genommen unterschiedliche Bedeutungen haben, und nur in Sonderfällen das "nächste" auch das "nähste" ist.